# When will a dev container be released with .NET SDK 6.0.400?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/dotnet shows latest available is 6.0.301.

How long until 6.0.400 is available?

Comment: You can build the container from https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/ and you don't need to wait for the preconfigured devcontainer image.

Answer (score 0):

So solution was to  switch the tag on the image to use `6.0`, which will be latest.

Also added to `devcontainer.json`:

```js
 "features": {
    "dotnet": {
      "version": "latest",
    },
}
```